# Using typescript + sveltekit, how can I pass in a svelte component as prop to another svelte component?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to pass in a component to my `PrimaryButton.svelte` component.

Essentially I'd want to be able to plug it in here:

```html
<svelte:component this={icon} />
```

However, I'm confused as to the type of `icon`. How do I define it properly in typescript?

```js
export let icon: {what goes here?} | undefined = undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

That would be `ComponentType` which can be imported from `'svelte'`.

The type is generic, the parameters can be used to further restrict e.g. the expected props.

Answer (score 1):

re: `ConstructorOfATypedSvelteComponent` - intellisense will hint:

> Ambient type only used for intellisense, DO NOT USE IN YOUR PROJECT.
>
> If you're looking for the type of a Svelte Component, use `SvelteComponent` and `ComponentType` instead:
>
> ```
> import type { ComponentType, SvelteComponent } from "svelte";
> let myComponentConstructor: ComponentType<SvelteComponent> = ..;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The type that you're looking for is `ConstructorOfATypedSvelteComponent`.

For example:

```
<script lang="ts">
    export let icon: ConstructorOfATypedSvelteComponent;
</script>

<svelte:component this={icon} />
```